# During Foreach read another foreach in powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach

Hi all powershell gurus out there.
I have a foreach which opens a URL from URLListl.txt and doing a Measure-command on them. The result from Measure-command writes to event-log. 
In another text file i have country list, like:
USA
Canada
Brazil
and so on....
I want in write eventlogs Message to read from this Text file and write it with the Measure-command result in Message part of the eventlog.
The below is my script which works fine but it creates two entries for each URL.

```
{
$URLListFile = "C:\yourname\URLList.txt"
$URLList = Get-Content $URLListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Foreach ($Uri in $URLList)
        {

        $Time = Measure-Command {
        C:\yourname\MainScript.ps1}
        $Time.TotalSeconds



$countrycode = (Get-Content c:\yourname\URLListcountry.txt)
  foreach ($SiteCode in $CountryCode)
        {
        $LogFileExist = Get-EventLog -list | Where-Object { $_.LogDisplayName -eq "Scriptcheck" }

        if (! $LogFileExist)
        {
            New-EventLog -LogName "Scriptcheck" -Source "Scripts"
        }
        if ($Time.Totalseconds -lt 25)
        {
            Write-EventLog -LogName "Scriptcheck" -Source "Scripts" -EntryType information -EventId 100 -Message " $SiteCode `nTotal Time: $Time"
        }
        elseif ($Time.Totalseconds -gt 25)
        {
            Write-EventLog -LogName "Scriptcheck" -Source "Scripts" -EntryType warning -EventId 101 -Message " $SiteCode  `nTotal Time: $Time"
        }  
        }
        }
```

}

if (Get-Process -name iexplore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
    Stop-Process -Name iexplore
    }
Measure-Site

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Never mind, i managed to fix it

Comment: @Donrsh, delete the question then ;) Or provide answer!